# Laravel get data from multiple tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have a **projects** table with the value of the following column:

```
id_project   name           website         country_id  currency_id  timezone_id
==========.  ====           =======         ==========. ===========. ===========
1            project name.  www.yahoo.com.  10          8            10
```

and a **countries** table with the value of the following column:

```
id_country.      country_name
==========.      ============
10               America
```

and a **currencies** table with the value of the following column:

```
id_currency      currency_name
===========      ============
8                BD
```

and a **timezones** table with the value of the following column:

```
id_timezone      time_onze    country_name
===========      =========    ============
10               Asia/Dhaka   Bangladesh
```

Now, I want to run a query that should give me **name**, **website**, **country_name**, **time_zone**, **currency_name**. BUT you can see the **country_name** is exist on both table which is **countries** and **timezones**. So, the query should give me the **country_name** from **countries** table NOT **time_zones** table.

So, for that I am running following query:

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')
->leftJoin('countries', 'projects.country_id', '=', 'countries.id_country')
->leftJoin('currencies', 'projects.currency_id', '=', 'currencies.id_currency')
->leftJoin('timezones', 'projects.timezone_id', '=', 'timezones.id_timezone')
->get(['name', 'website', 'code', 'projects.currency_name', 'time_zone']);

return response()->json($projects, 200);
```

But Can't get the data

Error message:

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'projects.currency_name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `name`,
> `website`, `code`, `projects`.`currency_name`, `time_zone` from
> `projects` left join `countries` on `projects`.`country_id` =
> `countries`.`id_country` left join `currencies` on
> `projects`.`currency_id` = `currencies`.`id_currency` left join
> `timezones` on `projects`.`timezone_id` = `timezones`.`id_timezone`)"

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: You should use ```currencies.currency_name``` instead of ```projects.currency_name``` because you have currency_name in currencies table not projects table.

Comment: @MuhammadHassanJaved OH Man, What a simple mistake!!!!

Comment: Please upvote my comment, I'm getting a lot of downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')
->leftJoin('countries', 'projects.country_id', '=', 'countries.id_country')
->leftJoin('currencies', 'projects.currency_id', '=', 'currencies.id_currency')
->leftJoin('timezones', 'projects.timezone_id', '=', 'timezones.id_timezone')
->get(['projects.name', 'projects.website', 'currencies.currency_name', 'timezones.time_zone']);

return response()->json($projects, 200);
```

or with select helper

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')
->leftJoin('countries', 'projects.country_id', '=', 'countries.id_country')
->leftJoin('currencies', 'projects.currency_id', '=', 'currencies.id_currency')
->leftJoin('timezones', 'projects.timezone_id', '=', 'timezones.id_timezone')
->select(
['projects.name', 'projects.website', 'currencies.currency_name', 'timezones.time_zone']
)
->get();

return response()->json($projects, 200);
```

There is no `code` column in your DB. So i dont include it. Sorry for my bad english

Hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are doing wrong query

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')
->leftJoin('countries', 'projects.country_id', '=', 'countries.id_country')
->leftJoin('currencies', 'projects.currency_id', '=', 'currencies.id_currency')
->leftJoin('timezones', 'projects.timezone_id', '=', 'timezones.id_timezone')
->get(['projects.name', 'projects.website, 'currencies.currency_name', 'timezones.time_zone']);

return response()->json($projects, 200);
```

I don't see any `code` column can you make sure where it's comes  from.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your column selection, as all the column names are unique you can totally ignore adding the table name in front of columns.

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')
->leftJoin('countries', 'projects.country_id', '=', 'countries.id_country')
->leftJoin('currencies', 'projects.currency_id', '=', 'currencies.id_currency')
->leftJoin('timezones', 'projects.timezone_id', '=', 'timezones.id_timezone')
->get(['name', 'website', 'currency_name', 'time_zone']);

return response()->json($projects, 200);
```

Comment: Do you think above query will work?

Comment: if I use the table name before the column then it's working.

Comment: Yes, as long as column names are unique. None of the name should exist in other tables.

Comment: Then you might have same column name in other tables as well.

Comment: The table structure you posted in post is complete or partial?

Comment: Its partial as the cull table structure is bit long.

Comment: Anyway, it's working for me.